# Permission setting of the pgAgent Job in the pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

The Jobs category shown in the `pgAdmin` seems to be only visible for the super user accounts.(see the screen below) . When I use the non super user accounts to login , I cannot see the jobs category.Is it possible to configure such that a non super users can also see the jobs category?

[image]

Comment: You'd need to be `grant`ed permission to view the job in question.

Comment: @Jack Maney how to grant? I cannot find anything about the permission setting on the job

Comment: You'll need to find the item (probably a function) in the `pgagent` schema that corresponds to the job and have someone with superuser access `grant` you permission to view it.  Take a look at the pgagent documentation:  http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.14/pgagent.html

Answer (score 1):

Go through the pgagent schema and grant appropriate privileges to all objects in that schema.

pgAgent creates all the tables, functions, etc. in a schema called pgagent in the relevant database.